# Laravel 4 - How to validate unique with multiple fields?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, schema

I have this schema:

```
Schema::create('members', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->integer('mname');

        $table->unique(array('lname', 'fname'));
    });
```

My problem is, how to validate these unique fields?

I tried this but I know this is wrong...

```
public static $rules = array(
    'lname' => 'unique:members',
    'fname' => 'unique:members'
);
```

Any help is appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 6):

You should use this package https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

use it like this:

```
$rules = array(
    '<field1>' => 'unique_with:<table>,<field2>[,<field3>,...,<ignore_rowid>]',
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'lname' => 'unique:members,lname',
    'fname' => 'unique:members,fname'
);


 'lname' => 'unique:members,lname',
                            ^^^^^ "lname" is a column of members table
```

More info:

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Comment: I think this would validate if each `lname` and `fname` is unique.. What I need to to validate both as unique combined..

Comment: In that case, you need a custom validation.